# SQL Stored Procedure run two selects and return a value

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How would I go about modifying stored procedure to run two SQL statements

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[hms_GetEmployeeSalaryRecordsByContractId]
(
@Id int
)
as
SELECT c.*
FROM  contract c
where c.emp_no =  @Id AND c.leave_date='1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' and c.main_contract=1

select * from salary s where s.contract_id = firstquery.contract_id
```

The above could find two salary records based on one contract

If multiple salaries are found, then I need to do a `sum(s.salary)` then return that as a     decimal value in the stored procedure.

I have done this so far now

```
 USE [pamsv83x]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[hms_GetEmployeeSalaryRecordsByContractId]    Script Date: 08/29/2013 10:45:05 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Create procedure [dbo].[hms_GetEmployeeSalaryRecordsByContractEmpNo]
(
@Id int,
@sallaryresult decimal(8,2) OUTPUT
)
as
DECLARE @contract_id int
DECLARE @totalsallary decimal(8,2)
set @contract_id=(SELECT c.contract_id
FROM  contract c
where c.emp_no =  @Id AND c.leave_date='1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' and c.main_contract=1)


SELECT *,SUM(salary)
from salary s 
where s.emp_no=@contract_id
return
```

Amend 2-----
    They can have multple contracts but can have multple sallarys

```
 Create procedure [dbo].[hms_GetEmployeeSalaryRecordsByContractEmpNo]
 (
@Id int,
@sallaryresult decimal(8,2) OUTPUT
)
as
DECLARE @contract_id int
DECLARE @totalsallary decimal(8,2)
set @contract_id=(SELECT c.contract_id
FROM  contract c
where c.emp_no =  @Id AND c.leave_date='1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')


SELECT *,SUM(salary + old_salary)
from salary s 
where s.contract_id=@contract_id
return
```

Comment: hi marc it can be multle sallarys as they can have different contracts so needs to add more than one if found base from the firstquery.contract id its for SQL 2008 R2

Comment: yes but look at my second amend putting this in now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A join of salary to contact would be the better way of doing this. Something like:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[hms_GetEmployeeSalaryRecordsByContractId]
(
@Id int
)
as
SELECT 
     c.contract_id
    ,SUM(s.salary + s.old_salary)       
FROM  
    contract c
INNER JOIN
    salary s
    ON c.contract_id = s.contract_id    
WHERE
        c.emp_no = @Id 
    AND c.leave_date = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
    AND c.main_contract = 1

GROUP BY
    c.contract_id
```

The above would accept an employee id and return an aggregated salary value by contact_id.

Comment: thank you very much kyle u took the efffor here I wish i could mark this up but my rep is not high enough is their any other way to give u praise ?